# Find the Galois group of $x^{4}-t$ over $\mathbb{R}(t)$, where $t$ is transcendental over the complex number $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This question is from exercise in Chapter VI Q1 (n) in Lang's algebra.

Find the Galois group of $x^{4}-t$ over $\mathbb{R}(t)$, where $t$ is transcendental over the complex number $\mathbb{C}$

In fact I don't have any ideas about this question. I have finished Q1 (a) through (l), but I am stuck in here without any thoughts...

The point here is that I don't get any intuition about the  transcendental element, and I think this question goes from here.

Any hints or explanations are highly appreciated!!!

**EDIT 1:**

Okay, for now, I learned something of the  transcendental element. Since $t$ is a transcendental element over $\mathbb{C}$, then it cannot be the root of any polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$.

However, if $t$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$, it must be transcendental over $\mathbb{R}$.

I have figured out the following thing, I will keep updating.

Comment: What would you say are the solutions of $x^4-t=0$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I am sorry I just edited my post. I don't quite understand  transcendental element, so I don't know what happens to the solutions of $x^{4}-t=0$

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so if we forget about the transcendental for a little while, $x^{4}-t=0$ gives us four solutions, $\sqrt[4]{t}$, $\zeta \sqrt[4]{t}$, $\zeta^{2} \sqrt[4]{t}$ and $\zeta^{3} \sqrt[4]{t}$, where $\zeta$ is the primitive fourth root of unity. However, can I do this if $t$ is transcendental?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the fact that $t$ is transcendental over $\Bbb{C}$ we can conclude that the polynomial is irreducible (I think that this is where they want you to go with this). Also, the roots of the polynomial must be distinct, so the extension is Galois.

**Edit** (additional explanation): Since $t$ is transcendental over $\Bbb{R}$, $\Bbb{R}[t]$ is isomorphic to a polynomial ring of $\Bbb{R}$ in one variable. So, $t$ is prime since it is irreducible. Then, by Eisenstein's criterion, $x^4-t$ is irreducible over the field of fractions of $\Bbb{R}[t]$ which is just $\Bbb{R}(t)$.

Call the splitting field of the polynomial $F$. Call the roots of the polynomial $\alpha_1,\cdots,\alpha_4$. In fact, if $\alpha$ is a root, then $-\alpha$ is a root. So we can just say that the roots are $\alpha_1,-\alpha_1,\alpha_2,-\alpha_2$. So $F=\Bbb{R}(t)(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$.
So $x^4-t=(x^2-\alpha_1^2)(x^2-\alpha_2^2)=x^4-(\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2)x^2+\alpha_1^2\alpha_2^2$. If $\alpha_2 \in \Bbb{R}(t)(\alpha_1)$, then $\alpha_2^2 \in \Bbb{R}(t)(\alpha_1)$, which would imply that there is some $a,b,c,d \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\alpha_2^2 = a + b\alpha_1+c\alpha_1^2+d\alpha_1^3$. but this would imply that $\alpha_1^2 + a + b\alpha_1+c\alpha_1^2+d\alpha_1^3 =0$ contradicting that $x^4-t$ is the minimal polynomial for $\alpha_1$ over $\Bbb{R}(t)$. So we have two extensions which are $\Bbb{R}(t)(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)/\Bbb{R}(t)(\alpha_1)$ and $\Bbb{R}(t)(\alpha_1)/\Bbb{R}(t)$. Use this information to find the Galois group of the extension.

Comment: Would you mind being more specific about why t being transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$ implies the polynomial irreducible and the roots are distinct? Since this is exactly the place where I am confused, I'd really like to get more detailed information. Thank you!

Comment: Also, why $\alpha_{2}^{2}=a+b\alpha_{1}+c\alpha_{1}^{2}+d\alpha_{1}^{3}$ implies $\alpha_{1}^{2}+\alpha_{2}^{2}=0$?

Comment: $\alpha_1^2 + \alpha_2^2=0$ since the coefficients of the polynomials need to be the same. I then plugged in the value for $\alpha_2^2$ into that.

Comment: Okay I just finished the computation, so the Galois group would be $\mathbb{Z_{2}}\times \mathbb{Z_{2}}$?

Comment: I don't think so since the degree of the extension is 8.

Comment: OH! I made a great mistake.. Sorry I have been working on algebra for a whole day...

Comment: Sorry I am late here but how $\alpha_2^2=a+b\alpha_1+c\alpha_1^2+d\alpha_1^3$ leads to a contradiction? Put $a=b=d=0$ and $c=-1$. This would satisfy the equation right? As $\alpha_1^2+\alpha_2^2=0$

Comment: I'm not sure what I was thinking at the time, but I think you are right. With what you said, the equation for the "contradiction" would simplify to $0=0$

Comment: For an actual contradiction, you can assume $\alpha_2=a_0+a_1\alpha_1+a_2\alpha_1^2+a_3\alpha_1^3$. This then gives that the square of that is $-\alpha_1^2$. It's easy to see (even without expanding; just from using the degree) that this implies that $a_0,a_2,a_3=0$. This implies that $a_1^2=-1$ which can't happen in $\mathbb{R}$